# Cache downloaded image in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView with an adapter that loads various data from an API. One of the data is a URL to an image online. I download the image and set it in my ImageView in the adapter.

The problem is though, when I scroll up and down in the ListView, images are re-downloaded and there is a significant lag when doing that. Also, for a split second, it incorrectly displays the wrong image.

I need to somehow cache these images to only download once and properly set them in that ListView - How do I do that?

EDIT: 
I use universal image loader to load my images like this:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, viewHolder.thumbnailImageView);
```

But it does not seem to cache them... Do I have to do something additional?

Comment: use an image library such as fresco to load and cache the images for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ImageLoaders

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(imageView);
```

Simple Image load. Check the link you can use them with listeners.

You can also try:

[picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

EDIT: As the OP said he uses UIL .

]You should use Image Aware.
You can have your own configuration with high cache memory something like this.

```
 public void initializeImageLoader(final Context sContext) {
        final ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(sContext)
                .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
                .taskExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
                .taskExecutorForCachedImages(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
                .threadPoolSize(3) // default
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) // default
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(50 * 1024 * 1024)) // default
                .memoryCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
                .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(sContext)) // default
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
```

Use this initialization before you get instance.

initializeImageLoader(context);
 ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

Set Options for your loader.

```
 final DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.noimage)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimage)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(false) //default
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(false) //default
                .build();
```

And set it to your loader:

```
final ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(viewHolder.thumbnailImageView, false);
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageAware, options);
```

Comment: I use the universal image loader to load my images but it does not seem to cache them... what do I have to do..?